# prop.table doesn't work in a for-loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

This may be a very simple question, but I don't see how to answer it.
I have the following reproducible code, where I have two small dataframes that I use to calculate a percentage value based on each column total:

```
#dataframe x
x <- structure(list(PROV = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "AG", class = "factor"), 
                    APT = structure(1:2, .Label = c("AAA", "BBB"), class = "factor"), 
                    PAX.2013 = c(5L, 4L), PAX.2014 = c(4L, 2L), PAX.2015 = c(4L,0L)), 
               .Names = c("PROV", "APT", "PAX.2013", "PAX.2014", "PAX.2015"), 
               row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

#dataframe y
y <- structure(list(PROV = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "AQ", class = "factor"), 
                    APT = structure(1:2, .Label = c("CCC", "AAA"), class = "factor"), 
                    PAX.2013 = c(3L, 7L), PAX.2014 = c(2L, 1L), PAX.2015 = c(0L,3L)), 
               .Names = c("PROV", "APT", "PAX.2013", "PAX.2014", "PAX.2015"), 
               row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")

#list z (with x and y)
z <- list(x,y)

#percentage value of x and y based on columns total
round(prop.table(as.matrix(z[[1]][3:5]), margin = 2)*100,1)
round(prop.table(as.matrix(z[[2]][3:5]), margin = 2)*100,1)
```

as you can see, it works just fine.
Now I want to automate for all the list, but I can't figure out how to get the results. This is my simple code:

```
#for-loop that is not working
for (i in length(z))
{round(prop.table(as.matrix(z[[i]][3:5]), margin = 2)*100,1)}
```

Comment: try `for(i in 1:length(z))` instead of `for(i in length(z))`. And explicitly `print(round(...))` in your loop

Comment: I knew this would have exposed my distraction... I didn't see that i was using length instead of seq_along! Printing is not really needed, I will use that table in other ways that I didn't want you to care much about! Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you have not put a range into your for loop so you are just trying to iterate over a single number and second, you are not assigning your result anywhere on each iteration.

Use `1:length(z)` to define a range.  Then assign the results to a variable.

This would work:

```
my_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(z)){
    my_list[[i]] <- round(prop.table(as.matrix(z[[i]][3:5]), 
                                     margin = 2)*100,1)
}
my_list
```

But it would be more efficient and idiomatic to use lapply:

```
lapply(1:length(z), 
   function(x) round(prop.table(as.matrix(z[[x]][3:5]), margin = 2)*100,1))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried lapply as well, but of course I had the same issue with length!

Answer (score 1):

Barring discussions whether for-loops is the best approach, you had two issues. One, your for loop only iterates over 2 (which is length(z)) instead of 1:2. Two, you need to do something with the round(....) statement. In this solution, I added a print statement.

```
for (i in 1:length(z)){
  print(round(prop.table(as.matrix(z[[i]][3:5]), margin = 2)*100,1))
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As commented above, I was sure it was a stupid issue, and indeed it was!